# How to check datetime column in pandas dataframe is continuous in terms of 15 minutes interval

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, timedelta

I have a timeseries of 15 minutes interval, I want to check if the data is continuous. Here it has a missing value on `2022-02-01 00:45:00+01:00` and `2022-03-31 23:30:00+01:00`

```
time                       consumption
2022-02-01 00:00:00+01:00    107.0
2022-02-01 00:15:00+01:00     57.0
*2022-02-01 00:30:00+01:00    177.0*
*2022-02-01 01:00:00+01:00     30.0*

2022-03-31 22:45:00+01:00     21.0
2022-03-31 23:00:00+01:00     25.0
*2022-03-31 23:15:00+01:00     43.0*
*2022-03-31 23:45:00+01:00     30.0*
```

I want the result as:

```
"2022-02-01 00:45:00+01:00" is missing
"2022-03-31 23:30:00+01:00" is missing
```

I would also like to check if the entire data is continuous in terms of 15 minute intervals:

```
true : it has complete values
false: missing at least one value
```

Comment: one way is use pct_change and then look for an deviation in the percent change from the previous time.  you can use a window to get the previous time and calculate a time delta and a pct change.

Comment: the yes/no question can be answered by `(df["time"].diff() == pd.Timedelta(minutes=15)).iloc[1:].all()` - however, it seems you're looking for the ***missing*** elements, assuming a 15-minute grid?

Answer (score 0):

you can use shift function to do the calculation

```py
#### setup of testing data
df = pd.DataFrame( data = { 'a' : [1,2,5,6,7,9,10] , 'b' : ['x','y', 'ds' , '3s' , 'sjfd' , 'sfa' , 'e' ] } )

df = pd.DataFrame(  { 'time' : ['2022-02-01 00:00:00+01:00' ,
                                      '2022-02-01 00:15:00+01:00',
                                      '2022-02-01 00:30:00+01:00',
                                      '2022-02-01 01:00:00+01:00',
                                      '2022-03-31 22:45:00+01:00',
                                      '2022-03-31 23:00:00+01:00',
                                      '2022-03-31 23:15:00+01:00',
                                      '2022-03-31 23:45:00+01:00'
                                     ] , 'consumption' : ['x','y', 'ds' , '3s' , 'sjfd' , 'sfa' , 'e' , 'kas'] }
                 )
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'] )


#### actual logic
df1 = df.shift(-1)
df['gap'] = (df1['time'] - df['time'] ).dt.total_seconds() / ( 15 * 60)
df
```

so you can a df like below. If the gap is equal to 1, there has it's next timestamp. If it is larger than one, you can derive which and how many timestamps are missing starting from that row.

For the last part, if all gap equal to 1 (except the last row), you have a complete values

```
    time    consumption gap
0   2022-02-01 00:00:00+01:00   x   1.0
1   2022-02-01 00:15:00+01:00   y   1.0
2   2022-02-01 00:30:00+01:00   ds  2.0
3   2022-02-01 01:00:00+01:00   3s  5655.0
4   2022-03-31 22:45:00+01:00   sjfd    1.0
5   2022-03-31 23:00:00+01:00   sfa 1.0
6   2022-03-31 23:15:00+01:00   e   2.0
7   2022-03-31 23:45:00+01:00   kas NaN
```